# Is there a way to measure a time spent for simulation? Does Q# support something like this?

Tags: q#

I want to measure the time spent for simulation of different algorithms to make some assumption about their efficiency.

I use Microsoft Azure Quantum SDK and VS Code setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the time spent in simulation (or resource estimation) from a Python wrapper for the Q# code. You'll need to create either a [Jupyter Notebook with both Q# and Python code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/how-to-submit-jobs?tabs=tabid-python&pivots=ide-jupyter#run-and-test-your-program-in-the-local-simulator) or a [Python host for Q# code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/how-to-submit-jobs?tabs=tabid-python&pivots=ide-python#run-and-test-your-program-in-the-local-simulator), and wrap the call to `qsharp.eval` or `qsharp.run` (or `qsharp.estimate`) in Python time-handling routines:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_time = datetime.now()
qsharp.eval("YourEntryPoint()")
end_time = datetime.now()
print(f"Simulation time: {end_time - start_time}")
```

I don't think there's a way to get simulation time when running Q#-only file in VS Code using "Run Q# file" command. (That could be an interesting improvement suggestion to file at https://github.com/microsoft/qsharp/issues)